# ffmpeg build with msys2 + VS2017 hang

Tags: visual-studio, ffmpeg, msys2

I am using windows10 + MSVC2017 Community + MSYS2 to build ffmpeg 4.0.1 with below steps:

1. Start a Visual Studio 2017 "**Developer Command Prompt**"
2. cd into msys64 directory, and then invoke MSYS2

   `msys2_shell.cmd -msys2 -use-full-path`
3. In MSYS2 shell, cd into ffmpeg build directory.
4. run ffmpeg config command:

   `./configure --prefix=./install --toolchain=msvc`

After press enter with above command line,sounds like it hang there forever.
never print anything out and not exit as well.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you are still looking for answers, but building FFmpeg in VS 2017 is well documented here: https://github.com/TechSmith/FFmpeg/tree/master/Windows

You may speed up the building process by only build the modules needed; also could use parallel build "make -j4" or the number of cores you want it to use to further speed it up.

A sample config file looks like this:

```
../../configure \
--toolchain=msvc \
--disable-programs \
--disable-doc \
--arch=x86_64 \
--enable-shared \
--disable-static \
--enable-cross-compile \
--target-os=win64 \
--extra-cflags="-MD" \
--disable-debug \
--disable-network \
--disable-autodetect \
--disable-encoders \
--disable-decoders \
--disable-filters \
--disable-muxers \
--disable-demuxers \
--disable-bsfs \
--disable-parsers \
--disable-protocols \
--disable-devices \
--enable-protocol=file \
--enable-decoder=h264,mp3*,aac,pcm*,mpeg4 \
--enable-demuxer=h264,mp4,mp3,avi,mov,aac \
--enable-parser=h264,aac,mpeg4video \
--enable-d3d11va \
--enable-hwaccel=h264_d3d11va \
--prefix=../../Build/Release
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not hang, that command cost much time! wait...

The brief steps:

1. Install MSYS2 tool.
2. Install build utility.

```
pacman -S make gcc diffutils mingw-w64-{i686,x86_64}-pkg-config mingw-w64-i686-nasm mingw-w64-i686-yasm
```

3. rename link.exe at /usr/bin to link.exe.bak to use msvc one.
4. launch msvc "developer command prompt".
5. run command from msys64 directory:

   `msys2_shell.cmd -mingw32 -use-full-path`
6. run build command:

```
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=$PKG_CONFIG_PATH:/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig
    ./configure --toolchain=msvc --arch=x86 --enable-yasm  --enable-asm --enable-shared --disable-static --disable-programs --enable-avresample --enable-libx264 --enable-gpl --prefix=./install
```